# Can we fetch the Latency (ping) of a Discord user using Discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In discord.py docs we have a method `client.latency` which return the latency of the Bot
But Actually I am asking if we can check the latency of other users something like This

> **User:** sd!ping @Mention

> **Bot:** XXms is the Ping of @Mention

**This is the default ping Command,**
**This Return the Latency of the Bot**

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')
```

Is there any method like `Mention.latency` Which will Return the Latency of the Mentioned User

> If it is Not Possible till now, please Let me know... Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord only allows you to view your own latency at this time. This feature won't likely be implemented as even normal users can't see other's latency in the voice channels.

You could try using a website and getting their latency from that and sending that to the bot for use. You might want to use Flask/Django or express.js for this.